# Dispatch barrier queues in GCD (iOS)

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm creating multiple concurrent queues in my application. `dispatch_barrier_sync` is used for modifying the shared resource.

Will `dispatch_barrier_sync` block parallel execution only in the current queue or across all queues?

For example, say I have 3 custom concurrent queues "A", "B", and "C".  If I submit a `dispatch_barrier_sync` block to the "A" queue, will it block parallel execution from "B" and "C"? Or only in "A"?

Comment: What did you learn from the test code that you wrote to investigate this?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I haven't coded fully yet..I wanted to know what happens in this case.So that i can rewrite it,incase of wrong

Comment: I didn't ask what your full code looks like, I asked what happened when you wrote some quick _tests_.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Did not have any test as of now.

Comment: @Karthik207 I think that Josh is suggesting you write some test code to figure out the answer, and post your results here.

Comment: Also, this question is easily answered by reading the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_barrier_sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only A. Exactly it will not block anything. It will just wait until all tasks in A will be finished. B and C will work as usual and could call their blocks.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_barrier_sync